# Shear a shape using mouse click in JS without a library, using html canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, mouseevent

I have made a shape by giving points using mouse click in html canvas. Now I have to click on any point and drag the mouseclick to another position and the shape should adjust accordingly(shear). But I want to do this by not using any library. I have look all around and have mostly found the code using some sort of a library. Can any one help? Is this possible with just JS?

```
html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
</style>

<body>
    <Canvas></Canvas>
</body>
<script>

    class point
    {
        constructor(x,y)
        {
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }
    }

    class shape
    {
        constructor(value)
        {
            value=value;
            //this.value=value;
        }


        drawShape(c,value,len)
        {
            var i=0;
            c.beginPath()
            c.moveTo(value[0].x,value[0].y)
            for(i=1;i<len;i++)
            {
                c.lineTo(value[i].x,value[i].y)
                c.moveTo(value[i].x,value[i].y)
            }
            c.lineTo(value[0].x,value[0].y)
            c.stroke()
        }
    }
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')

    // canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    // canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d')

    var points = {};
    var points2 = {};
    var p = {};
    var t = {};
    var house = {};
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var delt = 0;
    var mousePos = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        mousePos = getmouseposition(canvas, e);
        checkPoints(mousePos);
    },false);


    function checkPoints(mouse_pos) {
        if (i <= 9) {
            p[j] = new point(mouse_pos.x, mouse_pos.y);
            points[j] = p[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        } 
        else if (i == 10) {
            var house = {
                p: [0],
                p: [1],
                p: [2],
                p: [3],
                p: [4],
                p: [5],
                p: [6],
                p: [7],
                p: [8],
                p: [9]
            };

            shape = new shape(house);
            shape.drawShape(c, points, 9);
            j = 0;
            i++;
        } 
    }

    function getmouseposition(canvas, event) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: event.clientX - rect.left,
            y: event.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: theoretical you do the same as before. But instead of just capturing the coordinates when the mouse down event fires, you need to do the same repetitiv until the mouse up event fires again. Maybe you can try to create an interval on mouse down, that captures the mouse coordinates in a short interval and unregister this interval, as soon as the mouse up event fires. If you could provide some code would be a great help :)

Comment: thou i do understand your logic a little bit of code would help. and sorry i forgot the code. ill provide it asap.

Answer (score 0):

Now the thing to do is capturing of the mouses position repetitiv. You already use the click event. I would suggest here to listen to the mousedown event and call your check your mouse position inside of an interval. The return value of the interval must be saved in to a field of the class to remove it later on.

So adding a field for the intervalId in the class:

```
var points = {};
var points2 = {};
var p = {};
var t = {};
var house = {};
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var delt = 0;
var mousePos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
var intervalId;
```

doing the logic inside the interval:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
         mousePos = getmouseposition(canvas, e);
         checkPoints(mousePos);
    }, 500)
}, false);
```

Now you need to clear the inerval once the user releases the mouse button again. So we register another event handler for the mouseup event:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}, false);
```

The code is not tested and I haven't read through all your functions. This should just be some kind of guidance how I'd approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sebastian K. , thou the mouse down provides coords at regular intervals, sadly it only provides the first coord when the mouse down was fired and repeats it at regular intervals.

Comment: Could you try to bind a mousemove event when the mousedown event fires and unbind it on mouseup? I guess you won't be needing the interval anymore then.